# Why doesn't the text stretch across the entire width of the textview?

Tags: android, textview

I have a little problem with the text within my textview in Android Studio.

When I press the "Passwort generieren" button in my app, a random sequence of characters is put together into a string.

This randomly generated string then gets displayed in the textview which is highlighted green.

Strangely enough - as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNDhE.jpg) - the text breaks into the next line, even though the text field has not ended there.

Does anyone know why?

Here is the complete xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp">

            <Switch
                android:id="@+id/sDigit"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="Ziffern"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/divider" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="Wie lange soll das Passwort sein?"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sSpecialCharacter" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Was soll das Passwort enthalten?"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/sAutoCopy"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="Passwort automatisch kopieren"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnGenerate" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/sCharacterBig"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="Großbuchstaben"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sCharacter" />

            <Switch
                android:id="@+id/sCharacter"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="Buchstaben"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sDigit" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/sCharacterSmall"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="Kleinbuchstaben"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sCharacterBig" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnGenerate"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                android:text="Passwort generieren"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etLength" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/divider"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="#000000"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etLength"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:width="65dp"
                android:background="@drawable/border"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="3"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:text="100"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sSpecialCharacter" />

            <Switch
                android:id="@+id/sSpecialCharacter"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="Sonderzeichen"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sCharacterSmall" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvResultTopic"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="Das Passwort lautet"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sAutoCopy" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvResult"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:background="#23D52C"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                app:fontFamily="monospace"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvResultTopic" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is the xml code of the textview:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvResult"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="#23D52C"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:fontFamily="monospace"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvResultTopic" />
```

And just in case... here is my program code:

```
package com.example.passwortgenerator2

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import kotlin.collections.ArrayList
import kotlin.random.Random

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val arrayDigit = charArrayOf(
            '0',
            '1',
            '2',
            '3',
            '4',
            '5',
            '6',
            '7',
            '8',
            '9'
        )
        val arrayCharSmall = charArrayOf(
            'a',
            'b',
            'c',
            'd',
            'e',
            'f',
            'g',
            'h',
            'i',
            'j',
            'k',
            'l',
            'm',
            'n',
            'o',
            'p',
            'q',
            'r',
            's',
            't',
            'u',
            'v',
            'w',
            'x',
            'y',
            'z'
        )
        val arrayCharBig = charArrayOf(
            'A',
            'B',
            'C',
            'D',
            'E',
            'F',
            'G',
            'H',
            'I',
            'J',
            'K',
            'L',
            'M',
            'N',
            'O',
            'P',
            'Q',
            'R',
            'S',
            'T',
            'U',
            'V',
            'W',
            'X',
            'Y',
            'Z'
        )
        val arraySpecialChar = charArrayOf(
            '!',
            '"',
            '§',
            '$',
            '%',
            '&',
            '/',
            '(',
            ')',
            '=',
            '?',
            '`',
            '´',
            '~',
            '+',
            ',',
            ';',
            '.',
            ':',
            '-',
            '_',
            '^',
            '°',
            '|',
            '<',
            '>'
        )

        sCharacter.setOnClickListener {
            if (!sCharacter.isChecked)
            {
                sCharacterBig.isEnabled = false
                sCharacterSmall.isEnabled = false
            }
            else
            {
                sCharacterBig.isEnabled = true
                sCharacterSmall.isEnabled = true
            }
        }

        sCharacterBig.setOnClickListener {
            if (!sCharacterBig.isChecked)
            {
                if (!sCharacterSmall.isChecked)
                {
                    sCharacter.isChecked = false

                    sCharacterBig.isEnabled = false
                    sCharacterSmall.isEnabled = false

                    sCharacterBig.isChecked = true
                    sCharacterSmall.isChecked = true
                }
            }
        }

        sCharacterSmall.setOnClickListener {
            if (!sCharacterSmall.isChecked)
            {
                if (!sCharacterBig.isChecked)
                {
                    sCharacter.isChecked = false

                    sCharacterBig.isEnabled = false
                    sCharacterSmall.isEnabled = false

                    sCharacterBig.isChecked = true
                    sCharacterSmall.isChecked = true
                }
            }
        }

        btnGenerate.setOnClickListener {
            if (sDigit.isChecked || sCharacter.isChecked || sSpecialCharacter.isChecked)
            {
                if (etLength.text.toString().toInt() !== 0)
                {
                    if (!Regex("^0+[1-9]").containsMatchIn(etLength.text.toString()))
                    {
                        var password = String()
                        var arr: MutableList<CharArray> = ArrayList()

                        if (sDigit.isChecked && (sCharacter.isChecked && sCharacterBig.isChecked && sCharacterSmall.isChecked) && sSpecialCharacter.isChecked)  // 1 + 2 + 3 + 4
                        {
                            arr.add(0, arrayDigit)
                            arr.add(1, arrayCharSmall)
                            arr.add(2, arrayCharBig)
                            arr.add(3, arraySpecialChar)
                        }
                        else if ((sCharacter.isChecked && sCharacterSmall.isChecked && sCharacterBig.isChecked) && sSpecialCharacter.isChecked)                 // 2 + 3 + 4
                        {
                            arr.add(0, arrayCharSmall)
                            arr.add(1, arrayCharBig)
                            arr.add(2, arraySpecialChar)
                        }
                        else if (sDigit.isChecked && (sCharacter.isChecked && sCharacterBig.isChecked) && sSpecialCharacter.isChecked)                          // 1 + 3 + 4
                        {
                            arr.add(0, arrayDigit)
                            arr.add(1, arrayCharBig)
                            arr.add(2, arraySpecialChar)
                        }
                        else if (sDigit.isChecked && (sCharacter.isChecked && sCharacterSmall.isChecked) && sSpecialCharacter.isChecked)                        // 1 + 2 + 4
                        {
                            arr.add(0, arrayDigit)
                            arr.add(1, arrayCharSmall)
                            arr.add(2, arraySpecialChar)
                        }
                        else if (sDigit.isChecked && (sCharacter.isChecked && sCharacterSmall.isChecked) && sCharacterBig.isChecked)                            // 1 + 2 + 3
                        {
                            arr.add(0, arrayDigit)
                            arr.add(1, arrayCharSmall)
                            arr.add(2, arrayCharBig)
                        }
                        else if ((sCharacter.isChecked && sCharacterBig.isChecked) && sSpecialCharacter.isChecked)                                              // 3 + 4
                        {
                            arr.add(0, arrayCharBig)
                            arr.add(1, arraySpecialChar)
                        }
                        else if ((sCharacter.isChecked && sCharacterSmall.isChecked) && sSpecialCharacter.isChecked)                                            // 2 + 4
                        {
                            arr.add(0, arrayCharSmall)
                            arr.add(1, arraySpecialChar)
                        }
                        else if (sCharacter.isChecked && sCharacterSmall.isChecked && sCharacterBig.isChecked)                                                  // 2 + 3
                        {
                            arr.add(0, arrayCharSmall)
                            arr.add(1, arrayCharBig)
                        }
                        else if (sDigit.isChecked && sSpecialCharacter.isChecked)                                                                               // 1 + 4
                        {
                            arr.add(0, arrayDigit)
                            arr.add(1, arraySpecialChar)
                        }
                        else if (sDigit.isChecked && (sCharacter.isChecked && sCharacterBig.isChecked))                                                         // 1 + 3
                        {
                            arr.add(0, arrayDigit)
                            arr.add(1, arrayCharBig)
                        }
                        else if (sDigit.isChecked && (sCharacter.isChecked && sCharacterSmall.isChecked))                                                       // 1 + 2
                        {
                            arr.add(0, arrayDigit)
                            arr.add(1, arrayCharSmall)
                        }
                        else if (sSpecialCharacter.isChecked)                                                                                                   // 4
                        {
                            arr.add(0, arraySpecialChar)
                        }
                        else if (sCharacter.isChecked && sCharacterBig.isChecked)                                                                               // 3
                        {
                            arr.add(0, arrayCharBig)
                        }
                        else if (sCharacter.isChecked && sCharacterSmall.isChecked)                                                                             // 2
                        {
                            arr.add(0, arrayCharSmall)
                        }
                        else if (sDigit.isChecked)                                                                                                              // 1
                        {
                            arr.add(0, arrayDigit)
                        }

                        for (i in 1..etLength.text.toString().toInt())
                        {
                            var j = Random.nextInt(0, arr.size)
                            var k = Random.nextInt(0, arr[j].size)

                            password = password.plus(arr[j][k])
                        }

                        if (tvResultTopic.visibility == View.INVISIBLE)
                        {
                            tvResultTopic.visibility = View.VISIBLE

                            if (tvResult.visibility == View.INVISIBLE)
                            {
                                tvResult.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                            }
                        }

                        tvResult.text = password
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show your xml file textview ?

Comment: The TextView tries not to split lines in the middle of a word (approximately a sequence of letters and digits). Thus the split occurs earlier at a character not belonging to a word.

Comment: how would i know if i don't check the textview attributes , showing some code might help

Comment: Maybe that's causing the issue here. Do you have a solution for this problem? @Henry